# PayU integration in iOS not working

Tags: ios, payu

Please help me to find out the way to integrate PayU in iOS app successfully. Is there any proper document to follow i alsways getting issue with "key" and not wokring please help me

Comment: What did you tried so far? share some code that doesn't work.

Comment: Try to contact PayU SDK vendor. There are many types of integrations of payment gateway. Which specific type you want, you can decide after reading doc, and SDK comes with a pdf and sample project that helps programmer to integrate.

Comment: i was using  PayU SDK regarding PayU Document , i have got the solution regarding this 
that was my little issue for 
i was using -objc where as that should be -Objc
I have changed that and issue has been solved.
Thank you  for your input

Comment: find my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40947875/3548469, may it help you

Comment: If you are using swift then a good example is here : https://github.com/payu-intrepos/PayUMoney-IOS-SDK

Answer (score 0):

i was using PayU SDK regarding PayU Document , i have got the solution regarding this that was my little issue for i was using -objc where as that should be -Objc I have changed that and issue has been solved. Thank you for your input