# How to integrate PayUMoney in swift

Tags: ios, swift, payumoney

I want to integrate the **PayUMoney SDK** in my app using

I am using this link to integrate **PayUMoney**: [How to integrate PayU Money in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885632/how-to-integrate-payu-money-in-swift)

I can see only the option to pay by credit card referring to the link's sample code however it is not showing up the net banking option. I don't understand what I am doing wrong in my code.

Here's what I have tried -

```
import UIKit
import PlugNPlay
import CommonCrypto

class PaymentVC: UIViewController {
    
    var type = String()
    var email = String()
    var name = String()
    var phone = String()
    var address = String()
    var state = String()
    var zipcode = String()
    var officetype = Int()
var TotalAmmount = String()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       continueWithCardPayment()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func backButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
           
           self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
       }
       
    func continueWithCardPayment()

    {
       
             var paymentParam = PUMTxnParam()
            paymentParam.key = "Zegfsgh"
            paymentParam.merchantid = "7085776"
            paymentParam.txnID = "xyz"
            paymentParam.phone = "8770338859"
            paymentParam.amount = TotalAmmount
            paymentParam.productInfo = "Nokia"
            paymentParam.surl = "https://test.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php"
            paymentParam.furl = "https://test.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php"
            paymentParam.firstname = "john"
            paymentParam.email = "john@john.com"
            paymentParam.environment = PUMEnvironment.test
            paymentParam.udf1 = "udf1"
            paymentParam.udf2 = "udf2"
            paymentParam.udf3 = "udf3"
            paymentParam.udf4 = "udf4"
            paymentParam.udf5 = "udf5"
            paymentParam.udf6 = ""
            paymentParam.udf7 = ""
            paymentParam.udf8 = ""
            paymentParam.udf9 = ""
            paymentParam.udf10 = ""
            paymentParam.hashValue = self.getHashForPaymentParams(paymentParam)
        // paymentParam. = ""
        // Set this property if you want to give offer:
          // paymentParam.userCredentials = ""



                PlugNPlay.presentPaymentViewController(withTxnParams: paymentParam, on: self, withCompletionBlock: { paymentResponse, error, extraParam in
                    if error != nil {
                        UIUtility.toastMessage(onScreen: error?.localizedDescription, from: .none)
                    } else {
                        var message = ""
                        if paymentResponse?["result"] != nil && (paymentResponse?["result"] is [AnyHashable : Any]) {
                            print(paymentResponse!)
                            message = "Hello Asad sucess"
                            //                    message = paymentResponse?["result"]?["error_Message"] as? String ?? ""
                            //                    if message.isEqual(NSNull()) || message.count == 0 || (message == "No Error") {
                            //                        message = paymentResponse?["result"]?["status"] as? String ?? ""
                            //                    }
                        } else {
                            message = paymentResponse?["status"] as? String ?? ""
                        }
                  
                        
                        UIUtility.toastMessage(onScreen: message, from: .none)
                    }
                })

        PlugNPlay.presentPaymentViewController(withTxnParams: paymentParam, on: self, withCompletionBlock: .none)
        }

    func sha512(_ str: String) -> String {

        let data = str.data(using:.utf8)!
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        data.withUnsafeBytes({
            _ = CC_SHA512($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
        })
        return digest.map({ String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }).joined(separator: "")
        
        
        
    }
    
    func getHashForPaymentParams(_ txnParam: PUMTxnParam?) -> String? {
        let salt = "vw8LigfjD"
        var hashSequence: String? = nil
        if let key = txnParam?.key, let txnID = txnParam?.txnID, let amount = txnParam?.amount, let productInfo = txnParam?.productInfo, let firstname = txnParam?.firstname, let email = txnParam?.email, let udf1 = txnParam?.udf1, let udf2 = txnParam?.udf2, let udf3 = txnParam?.udf3, let udf4 = txnParam?.udf4, let udf5 = txnParam?.udf5, let udf6 = txnParam?.udf6, let udf7 = txnParam?.udf7, let udf8 = txnParam?.udf8, let udf9 = txnParam?.udf9, let udf10 = txnParam?.udf10 {
            hashSequence = "\(key)|\(txnID)|\(amount)|\(productInfo)|\(firstname)|\(email)|\(udf1)|\(udf2)|\(udf3)|\(udf4)|\(udf5)|\(udf6)|\(udf7)|\(udf8)|\(udf9)|\(udf10)|\(salt)"
        }



        let hash = self.sha512(hashSequence!).description.replacingOccurrences(of: "<", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ">", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

        return hash
    }
    
    func paymentResponseReceived(notify:NSNotification) {
    print(notify)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this code? >> PlugNPlay.setDisableNetbanking = false

Comment: Also, check the PayU Money documentation for iOS, here's the link to it https://developer.payumoney.com/ios/